# Basic tic tac toe JS

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple tic-tac-toe game in by using a HTML table. I currently am able to add the "X" and "O" values onto the HTML table by changing a variable to either true or false. However I am unable to add a function to take turns. When the user clicks on any of the table cell it should start with "X" then "O". I have tried nested loops (for loops & do while) but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
function X()
{
    this.innerHTML = "X";
}
function O()
{
    this.innerHTML = "O";
}

function XDO()
{
    for (i = 1 ; i <=9;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("cell"+i).onclick = X;
    }
}

function ODO()
{
    for (i = 1 ; i <=9;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("cell"+i).onclick = O;
    }
}

var turn = true;
if(turn==true)
{
    XDO(); 
}
else if(turn==false)
{
    ODO();
```

Comment: No fiddle? Anyway, the code is incomplete.

Comment: I would suggest making a fiddle, as DontVoteMeDown suggests.  Additionally, your logic should be on the click of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `onClick` event handler to the cells that set the value of the cell to either X or O depending on a global flag *and invert the flag* (provided you want the game to be played on the same computer).

Like this:

```
function onCellClick() {
    if (turn)
        this.innerHTML = "X";
    else
        this.innerHTML = "O";

    turn = !turn;
}
```

Comment: compressed version: `this.innerHTML=(turn=!turn)?'X':'O';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your logic on the clicking of a cell, for this to work, there is no way for this function to execute the turn condition.

Setup a simple variable to hold the current turn and use an object to dictate what happens on that turn value (avoids if and switch logic).

```
var currentTurn = "X";
        var turns = {
          "X": function(element) {
             element.innerHTML = "X";
             },
          "O": function(element) {
             element.innerHTML = "O";
             }
    }
```

Then you need to set the onclick function for each cell, this will be doTurn

```
document.getElementById("cell"+i).onclick = doTurn;
```

In doTurn, we can swap the current turn value and then run the appropriate turn logic.

```
function doTurn()
{
    currentTurn = currentTurn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    turns[currentTurn](this);
}
```

I admit that this solution is more verbose, however, it uses some good practices/methodologies (intro to use of the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/strategy-design-pattern) and allows you to expand on your turn logic if you would like.